# Surprising results of Ms Azure vs Google Colab BERT training performance, not sure how to explain

Tags: azure, google-colaboratory, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm not sure if it's BERT related or not, had no chance to test other models, but did it for BERT.

So what I noticed recently that training algorithms and data that I used to work with in google colab for free, are seemed to work significantly slower in Azure ML workspace which we pay for.

I made the comparison - same data file (classification problem, sentiment analysis of 10K reviews), totally same notebook code (copy+paste), same latest ver of ktrain lib installed on both, both must be on Python 3.8, but GPU is a bit more performant on a colab side.

Results surprised me to say the least: google lab made its job **10 times faster: 17 min vs 170 min**, and it's reproducible. Tesla T4 (colab) is faster than K80 (azure) indeed, but not that much as per known benchmarks. So I wonder what else could matter. Is it virt. environment created in Azure ML performing so slow? If you have any idea what it could be, or what else I can check on both sides to reveal it, please share

BTW google gives you T4 in colab for your experimentations for free, while you have to pay for slower K80 at Azure.

**Google colab**
execution time = 17 min
[image]
**Google colab hardware**: cpu model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, memory 13Gb, GPU:
[image]

**Azure**
execution time = 2h50m = 170min (10x of colab)
[image]
**Azure hardware information**
[image]

K80 and T4 comparison: https://technical.city/en/video/Tesla-K80-vs-Tesla-T4

Comment: Any update on this? I am also experiencing very slow training on Azure. Thanks

Comment: no, unfortunately I have not figured that out, my coworkers have no idea either. Let me start a bounty for the question

Answer (score 2):

So I think firstly, to do a comparison that isn't apples-to-apples in terms of hardware, you'll struggle to get to the root of the issue.

That being said, on Azure, the Standard_NC6 compute target only gives half of a K80 card. I'm not sure how that 'half' divides all the specs, but I do know that it only gives half the GPU memory. From this, I'd assume that it also only gives half the CUDA cores, but maybe not half the bandwidth of the memory bus.

Lastly, the T4 has nearly double the boost clock speed of the K80, which might not give the 10x discrepancy you're seeing but will definitely have a substantial impact on performance.

I'd suggest maybe provisioning a K80 on the colab notebook, or any other gpu enabled compute that is available on both to test any theories you have about performance on the two platforms.

Answer (score -1):

There are different Azure VM Types available with different GPUs for different use-cases:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu

The NCv3 or NC T4_v3 Series also will provide you with a Tesla T4 GPU.
Maybe give those a try as well.

Comment: I do not have an access to Tesla T4 in my subscription unfortunately, but I do not think we might expect x10 performance improving running the same on T4. There is definetly something else behind it, besides the hardware differences